# How to apply XSLT to 2 xml files by combining them based on the 'name' tag?

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, teamcity, testcomplete

I have 2 xml files. ProjectLog.xml which has the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProjectLog>
  <ProjectLogItem id="0" pid="-1" nety="False">       
    <No>1</No>
    <Name><![CDATA[CanEnterInvoice]]></Name>
    <StartTime>12/03/2012 11:55:59</StartTime>
    <EndTime>12/03/2012 11:58:26</EndTime>
    <RunTime>0:02:26</RunTime>
    <Details>&lt;a href="#" onclick="top.logtree_openNode('{85E6CF42-8907-4565-B7C5-487AA089CE5C}')"&gt;Details&lt;/a&gt;</Details>
    <Messages/>
  </ProjectLogItem>     
</ProjectLog>
```

and root.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LogData name="DetailedTest" id="{719C8118-F2D1-4775-A46B-B9465ACBA1EC}" status="0">
  <Provider name="Project Log" schemaType="aqds:tree" href="ProjectLog.xml"/>
  <Provider name="Test Run Summary" schemaType="aqds:text" href="TestRunSummary.xml"/>
  <LogData name="CanEnterInvoice" id="{85E6CF42-8907-4565-B7C5-487AA089CE5C}" status="0">
    <Provider name="Project Log" schemaType="aqds:tree" href="CanEnterInvoice\ProjectLog.xml"/>
    <LogData name="Script Test Log [EnteringInvoice\EnteringInvoice]" id="{6B048A3D-0C3D-4FAC-9BA8-4703759F868D}" status="0">
      <Provider name="Test Log" schemaType="aqds:tree" href="CanEnterInvoice\ScriptTestLogEnteringInvoiceEnteringInvoice\TestLog.xml"/>
    </LogData>
  </LogData>
</LogData>
```

These 2 files are generated by Testcomplete after running tests and I am in the process of integrating testcomplete with teamcity. I am using teamcity MSBuild to run the tests and then once these log files are generated I am using XSLT to process the ProjectLog.xml and produce a text file that teamcity can read and display the test results. But when the results are read from ProjectLog.xml file it is not possible to determine if the test passed/failed. so I need to use the root.xml file to find the test result. The status attribute in the following xml in 'root.xml' file

```
<LogData name="CanEnterInvoice" id="{85E6CF42-8907-4565-B7C5-487AA089CE5C}" status="0">
```

tells whether the test passed or not. Right now I have the following XSLT to get the test name and duration from ProjectLog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:for-each select="ProjectLog/ProjectLogItem">      

       ##teamcity[testStarted name='<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>']
       ##teamcity[testFinished name='<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>' duration='<xsl:value-of select="RunTime"/>']       
         </xsl:for-each>           
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I am not sure how to update it to get the 'status' from the 'root.xml' for each test.

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with your question about XSLT, but, by chance, I have a script (**VBScript**) that gets the summary of the current test run and puts it in a readable format to a text file. This script should be specified as the last test item in a project. Hope this can help.

```
Sub ShowSummary
  summary = GetSummary
  Log.Message summary
  Call aqFile.WriteToTextFile("c:\MySummaryFile.txt", summary, aqFile.ctANSI, True)
End Sub

Function GetSummary
  tempFolder = aqEnvironment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp") & "\" & GetTickCount & "\"

  aqFileSystem.CreateFolder tempFolder
  Call Log.SaveResultsAs(tempFolder, lsXML)

  Set xDoc = Sys.OleObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")
  xDoc.load(tempFolder & "RootLogData.dat")                                              
  summaryFileName = xDoc.selectSingleNode("//Node[@name='item 0']/Prp[@name='filename']/@value").text
  xDoc.load(summaryFileName)

  GetSummary = "Total: "    & xDoc.selectSingleNode("Nodes/Node[@name='root']/Node[@name='summary']/Node[@name='total']/Prp[@name='total']/@value").text & VbCrLf &_
               "Executed: " & xDoc.selectSingleNode("Nodes/Node[@name='root']/Node[@name='summary']/Node[@name='executed']/Prp[@name='total']/@value").text & VbCrLf &_
               "Passed: "   & VarToStr(VarToInteger(xDoc.selectSingleNode("Nodes/Node[@name='root']/Node[@name='summary']/Node[@name='passed']/Prp[@name='total']/@value").text) + 1) & VbCrLf &_
               "Failed: "   & xDoc.selectSingleNode("Nodes/Node[@name='root']/Node[@name='summary']/Node[@name='failed']/Prp[@name='total']/@value").text

  Set xDoc = Nothing
  Call aqFileSystem.DeleteFolder(tempFolder, True) 
End Function
```